# In polars, is there a way to remove character accents from string columns?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to remove character accents from a text column, ex. convert Piña to Pina.
This is how I would do it in pandas:

```
(names
 .str.normalize('NFKD')
 .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
 .str.decode('utf-8'))
```

Polars has str.decode and str.encode but they don't seem to be what i'm looking for.
Thanks!

Comment: pandas calls [`unicodedata.normalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) e.g. `.apply(lambda s: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode())`

Comment: Thanks for this! Looks like `.apply` is the way to go. I'm surprised that pandas is not actually vectorized.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/strings/object_array.py#L446 if curious. As for polars, there is an open request for a fast/native implementation: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @jqurious's comment you can do one of two things:

1. apply/lambda

like this:

```
from unicodedata import normalize 
df.with_columns(
    a=pl.col('a')
        .apply(lambda x: normalize('NFKD',x)
                        .encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
                        .decode('utf-8')))
```

2. define function/map

like this:

```
from unicodedata import normalize 
def custnorm(In_series):
    for i, x in enumerate(In_series):
        newvalue = normalize('NFKD',x).encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')
        if newvalue != x:
            In_series[i]=newvalue
    return In_series
```

then inside the df you can do

```
df.with_columns(a=pl.col('a').map(custnorm))
```

The difference between apply and map is that apply tells polars to do the looping one row at a time whereas map tells polars to feed the whole column as a `Series` to the function which must then return a `Series` of the same size.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like `.apply` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This topic has come up again [on the issues tracker.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11455)

It seems there is an (undocumented?) [`pyarrow.compute.utf8_normalize()`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/22df70a0caf888084ae13d7f3e0178a477d1e7d7/python/pyarrow/tests/test_compute.py#L3210) function.

It could be a potential alternative until a fully native version is implemented.

```py
import polars as pl
import pyarrow.compute as pc

df = pl.DataFrame({"names": ["Piña", "⁴²"]})

pl.from_arrow(
    pc.utf8_normalize(
       df.get_column("names").to_arrow(),
       "NFKD"
    )
).str.replace_all(r"\p{CombiningMark}", "")
```

```
shape: (2,)
Series: '' [str]
[
    "Pina"
    "42"
]
```